# SQL insert if doesn't exist with another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the below script which creates a record in `USEROUT` if the User exists in `MOMUSER` but does not exist in `USEROUT`. But, I need check one more column in `USEROUT` called `FILENAME` to make sure we create the record if the user doesn't already have a recorder in `USEROUT` for the FILENAME `FORM.FRX`... have tried many things -- any ideas?

```
 INSERT INTO USEROUT (CUSER, FILENAME)
 SELECT MOMUSER.CODE, 'FORM.FRX'
 FROM MOMUSER
 LEFT JOIN USEROUT ON MOMUSER.CODE = USEROUT.CUSER 
 WHERE USEROUT.CUSER IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Not Exists` and get your desired result :

```
  INSERT INTO USEROUT (CUSER, FILENAME)
  SELECT MOMUSER.CODE, 'FORM.FRX'
  FROM MOMUSER
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1 FROM USEROUT WHERE CUSER = MOMUSER.CODE AND FILENAME = 'FORM.FRX')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  If  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM USEROUT WHERE CUSER = MOMUSER.CODE AND FILENAME = 'FORM.FRX')
      Begin
           INSERT INTO USEROUT (CUSER, FILENAME)
           SELECT MOMUSER.CODE, 'FORM.FRX'
           FROM MOMUSER
      End
```

you can also use this query.